# Change color of specific characters in MATLAB Edit Text

Tags: matlab, text, rtf, matlab-guide, textedit

I used two MATLAB Edit Texts to display data side by side.

I would like to highlight the differences between the two Edit Texts.  The characters which are different should appear in red.  Is there any method to achieve this?

An example of the intended output is shown:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not officially supported, as far as I know, but you can do this with HTML and bunch of hacking around with undocumented functions and Java. [This post on the Undocumented Matlab site](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/rich-matlab-editbox-contents) goes through the gory details. In particular, you'll need the [`findjobj`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/findjobj-find-underlying-java-object/) utility from the MathWorks File Exchange.

Comment: This is somewhat tedious to implement, but nonetheless it works.